Show that $\int_{1/2}^1\frac{\log(x+e)}{\log(x^2+e)}dx>\frac{1}{2}$
Q How to show that $$\int_{1/2}^{1}\frac{\log(x+e)}{\log(x^2+e)}dx>\frac{1}{2}$$
How I tried it:
I let $f(x)=\log(x+e)$ taking the derivative we get $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x+e}>0 \forall x\in(-e,+\infty)$
So the integral becomes $$\int_{1/2}^{1}\frac{f(x)}{f(x^2)}dx$$ Here I am stuck . Only meaningful information we have is that $\log(x+e)\leq x+e+1$ and $\log(x^2+e)\leq x^2+e+1$. Any help would be appreciated !

For all $x\in (1/2,1)$ we have $x^2<x$, and so $x^2+e<x+e$.
Given that $\log$ is an increasing function we then have $$\log(x+e)>\log(x^2+e)\iff \dfrac{\log(x+e)}{\log(x^2+e)}>1$$
Thus, $$\int_{1/2}^1 \dfrac{\log(x+e)}{\log(x^2+e)}\,dx>\int_{1/2}^1 1\, dx=\dfrac{1}{2}$$

$0<x<1\implies 0<x^2<x$.
$\frac{\log(x+e)}{\log(x^2+e)}=\frac{\log(\frac{x+e}{x^2+e})}{\log(x^2+e)}+1$
The term on the  left of the plus sign is always positive, so the function itself is always greater than 1.
This means if you assume the function is 1 over the entire interval, you get a lower bound for the integral. The resulting integral is $1/2$ thus the desired inequality follows.

Let's go by finding/estimating the value of the integral.
The value of the integral at x=0.5 is which will be just greater than one so we can assume it 1 then finding the value at x=1 gives us 1.
By basic principle of integration lets find the area of the rectangle formed by the lines x=0.5 , x=1 and y=1 so the area gives us 0.5 which means the value of integral is clearly more than 0.5. **Because we assumed the value at x=0.5 is nearly one but we know that it is slightly more than one so the area formed by the curve will be more than 0.5.. **
